# How can I install the Fantomas Tool with the latest version?

Tags: f#, fantomas

I installed the F# formatter tool, fantomas, globally and have this:

```
dotnet tool list -g
Package Id         Version      Commands
-----------------------------------------
fantomas-tool      4.7.9        fantomas
```

Updating as of today gives

```
dotnet tool update fantomas-tool -g
Tool 'fantomas-tool' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '4.7.9').
```

So no change. How can I ever get a later version? There is no version list in the repo or in the docu as well, only implicity version 5.2 is mentioned.

I tried commands like

```
dotnet tool update fantomas-tool -g --version 5
```

or "5.2" or "v5.2" but nothing helps. I cannot find any doc explaining how to install a later version, while the doc talks everywhere about the later versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 5, the name of the package has changed from `fantomas-tool` to just `fantomas`. So you should uninstall `fantomas-tool` and install `fantomas` instead.